# Java csv library to create Map of Map given a relationship matrix

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file which defines the relationship between different currencies. So to know relationship between one currency to another, I decided to have Map of Map where key will be source currency name and value will be again Map(key: target currency name, value: relationship type). By having such data structure I can do tail recursion to find relations between source and target currency.

Sample csv file:
/   AUD     CAD     CNY     CZK     DKK     EUR     GBP     JPY     NOK     NZD     USD 
AUD     1   USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     D 
CAD     USD     1   USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     D 
CNY     USD     USD     1   USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     D

To create such data structure I created below method but it looks too verbose. So I want to know if there is already existing library which can solve my purpose. I tried apache common IO but couldn't get what I am looking for.
method:
                                                                        public static Map> generateCurrencyMatrix(
            String currencyMatrixFilePath) {
        Map> currMatrixContext = 
   new HashMap>();
        Map termCurrencies = new HashMap();

```
    // try with resources to close in case of exception
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            currencyMatrixFilePath))) {
        String line;
        boolean headerLineIndicator = true;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (headerLineIndicator) {
                List<String> termCurr = Arrays.asList(line
                        .split(Constant.delimiter));
                IntStream.range(1, termCurr.size()).forEach(i -> {
                    termCurrencies.put(i, termCurr.get(i).trim());
                });
                headerLineIndicator = false;
            } else {
                List<String> relationship = Arrays.asList(line
                        .split(Constant.delimiter));
                Map<String, String> relation = new HashMap<String, String>();
                IntStream.range(1, relationship.size()).forEach(
                        i -> {
                            relation.put(termCurrencies.get(i).trim(),
                                    relationship.get(i).trim());
                        });
                currMatrixContext.put(relationship.get(0).trim(), relation);
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currMatrixContext;
}
```

Comment: does the parameterized version of that map look like Map<String, List<String>> context; where the key is the columnName and the values are the column? then referenced backwards by relationship as relations<String, String> where the value is a key in a column and a key is in the value?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I didn't understood the requirement, I think you can try MultiValueMap.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is your purpose and if this will help you reach it but you can try
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ it's very convenient for working with csv files.